# Can a singular or plural verb ("is" or "are") be used when the subject is a coordination?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions, copular-verbs

In the sentence:

> *The dimensions and shape **is/are** a little different than the rest.*

Should I be using 'is' or 'are', or can either be used?

Comment: As for an answer to your question: it depends. :) You might have a context where you are considering the subject to be notionally a singular, and so, you'll like to use "is". Or, it might be due to the close proximity of the singular "shape" that is causing you to be unsure. Usually, an "and" coordination would be considered to be plural--but there are many exceptions (e.g. *"Ham and eggs is what I want"*). Consider what your ear would prefer if the coordinates were switched: *"The shape and dimensions **is/are** a little different than the rest"*; but do this in the context of your text.

Comment: If your ear still prefers the singular "is" (for both versions), then you are probably considering the subject of your original sentence to be notionally singular.